# Map multiple rows based on cumulative value to another reference row in the same table

Tags: sql, sql-server, self-join

I have SQL table as below:

| PO | Delivery_Type | Scheduled_Line_Item | Date | Quantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | Scheduled Delivery | 01 | 01/12/2021 | 100,000 |
| 100 | Scheduled Delivery | 02 | 07/12/2021 | 75,000 |
| 100 | Actual Delivery | NULL | 03/12/2021 | 50,000 |
| 100 | Actual Delivery | NULL | 12/12/2021 | 50,000 |
| 100 | Actual Delivery | NULL | 15/12/2021 | 20,000 |
| 100 | Actual Delivery | NULL | 31/12/2021 | 55,000 |

I am trying to map out the Actual Delivery items to particular Scheduled_Line_Item based on the sequence of delivery date, to produce result as below:

| PO | Delivery_Type | Scheduled_Line_Item | Date | Delivered_Qty | Scheduled_Qty |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | Actual Delivery | 01 | 03/12/2021 | 50,000 | 100,000 |
| 100 | Actual Delivery | 01 | 12/12/2021 | 50,000 | 100,000 |
| 100 | Actual Delivery | 02 | 15/12/2021 | 20,000 | 75,000 |
| 100 | Actual Delivery | 02 | 31/12/2021 | 55,000 | 75,000 |

As you can see from above, the first two rows are mapped to "Scheduled_Line_Item" "01" because the sequence of Date have fulfilled the first 100,000 of the quantity in the Scheduled Delivery. Once the "Actual Delivery" has fulfilled the first "Schedule Delivery", then only we move to the next "Schedule Delivery" which is why the next two rows are mapped to "Scheduled_Line_Item" "02".

I found this method but unable to apply it to my requirements https://sqlsunday.com/2019/09/16/calculating-invoice-settlements/ .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `PO` + `Date` is unique for 'Actual Delivery' you can match running totals excluding repeated rows

```
with sd as (
   select *, sum(Quantity) over(partition by PO order by date) s
   from tbl
   where Delivery_Type ='Scheduled Delivery'
),
ad  as (
  select *, sum(Quantity) over(partition by PO order by date) s
   from tbl
   where Delivery_Type ='Actual Delivery'
)
select top(1) with ties sd.*, ad.*
from sd
left join ad on ad.PO=sd.PO and sd.s>= ad.s 
order by row_number() over(partition by ad.PO, ad.Date order by sd.date)
```